# array files downloader with nodejs axios and async await pattern in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, stream, axios

i have a problem with a script write in vanilla javascript and runs in nodejs. What i want to get is:

```
// Get axios request
  // response stream
  // download file1..........finish
// When file is downloaded 
// go to the next request 

// Get axios request
  // response stream
  // download file2..........finish
// When file is downloaded 
// go to the next request
```

I write this script in node and async await pattern

```js
// ARRAY OF BOOKS 
ex. [{title: 'awesome book', link: 'http://www.example.com/awesome_book.pdf'},
     {title: 'new book', link: 'http://www.example.com/new.pdf'} ...etc]
const Books = require('./Books');

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const axios = require('axios');


// 1)
// loop the array of books and create array of links
let booksLinkinkArray = Books.map( book => book.link);

// 2)
// Function get request with axios
// response is stream
function request (element) {
  try{
    return axios({
      url: element,
      method: "GET",
      responseType: "stream"
    });
  } catch(e) {
    console.log( 'errore: ' + e)
  }
}


// 3)
// Function that downloads the file
async function download(urls) {
  urls.map(async url => {
    try{
      const saveFile = await request(url);
      let file = url.split('/')[3];
        console.log(file + ' :  ' + 'init download');
      let download = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'books_dir', file));
      saveFile.data.pipe(download);
      console.log(file + ' :  ' + 'downloaded')

    } catch(e) {
      console.log( 'error: ' + e)
    }

  }) }

download(booksLinkinkArray);
```

This script is ok , but the loop of request is too fast, and file downloads overlap as:

```
// get request
// response
//download file init
// get request
// response
//download file init
ect...

file 1.......
file 2........
file 1...........
file 2..........
file 2.............. finish
file 1.............. finish
```

Is there a way to manage the stream so that the call is only be done after all the chuncks have been drained from the stream?

thanks for any replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
async download(urls){
  for(const url of urls) {
     const saveFile = await request(url);
     const file = url.split('/')[3];
     const download = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'books_dir', file));
     await new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        saveFile.data.pipe(download);
        download.on("close", resolve);
        download.on("error", console.error);
     });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async download(){
  for(const url of urls) {
    .....
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, same result
`async function download(urls) {
  for (const url of urls) {
      try {
        const saveFile = await request(url);
        let file = url.split('/')[3];
        saveFile.data.on('end', _ => {
          console.log(file + ' :  ' + 'init');
          let download = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'book_dir', file));
          saveFile.data.pipe(download);
        });
        console.log(file + ' :  ' + 'downloaded')
     
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error: ' + e)
      }
  }
}
download(booksLinkinkArray); `

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const axios = require('axios');

function request (element) {
    try{
        return axios({
        url: element,
        method: "GET",
        responseType: "stream"
        });
    } catch(e) {
        console.log( 'errore: ' + e)
    }
}

async function download(url){
    const saveFile = await request(url);
    const file = url.split('/')[3];
    const download = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'tmp', file));
    new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        saveFile.data.pipe(download);
        download.on("close", resolve);
        download.on("error", console.error);
    });
}

for(const url of booksLinkinkArray) {
    download(url);
}
```